# Where is Iyov buried?

Tags: history

I was researching where the tomb of the prophets were and saw that the tomb of Iyov is claimed to be in Oman. Do we know if he's buried there?

Comment: That location is not recognized by Judaism. It is a Muslim site. There are Jewish opinions that day Iyov never even existed, but is instead a moshol.

Comment: along with Ezra's opinion, are various opinions that Iyov lived at different times and in different places.

Comment: @ezra The only difference between a Jewish and a Muslim biblical gravesite is usually who lives nearby to make a big deal about it.

Comment: @DoubleAA The site is not recognized by Judaism

Comment: maybe yet, but just wait till Chabad opens a franchise in Oman for visiting israelis...

Comment: @DoubleAA you have a point. Last summer I was part of a team who excavated in Tel Tibnah in Israel. The hill opposite us has some nice 2nd Temple-era tombs, one of which was identified by Victor Guérin in the mid-19th century as Joshua's tomb (Tibnah is identified by some with Timnat Cheres). The excavation received some media hype and by the end of the season, people mistakenly came by our site because they were looking for Kever Yehoshua. It was a bit funny, considering that until then, only some 19th-early-20th scholars had ever accepted Guérin's theory.